# Querying for result in one time window that doesn't exist in another

Tags: sql, db2

The below query works but I want to modify it slightly.

As it is, it selects all customers from the customer table that aren't in an array from a previous function in this file (Hence the 'NOT IN ($dealerNum'). It runs the query on all other customers, and retrieves their number if they had orders in the 12 months preceding the last 6 months (I'm working in an 18 month window).

I need to change this slightly. I still want to run this on any customer that's not in the previous array. However, I want to retrieve the number of any customer that had orders in the last 6 months but NOT the 12 months prior to that. Basically showing they were in active for at least that year/12 months and have been active in the last 6 months.

Hopefully, that makes sense. Here's the existing query, I'm just not sure the best/most logical way to modify my WHERE to handle this

```
SELECT c.customerNumber
  FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Orders G ON C.CustomerNumber = G.Customer
WHERE c.customerNumber NOT IN ($dealerNum)
    AND C.date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 18 MONTHS AND CURRENT_DATE - 6 MONTHS
GROUP BY C.customerNumber
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Comment: Do you mean `C.date` I would expect the date to be from the `Orders` table -i.e. an OrderDate

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  c.customerNumber
from    Customers c
join    Orders o
on      c.CustomerNumber = o.Customer
where   c.customerNumber not in ($dealerNum)
group by
        c.customerNumber
having  count(case when o.date > current date - 6 months then 1 end) > 0
        and count(case when o.date between current date - 18 months and 
                            current_date - 6 months then 1 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write it like this

```
SELECT c.customerNumber
  FROM Customers C
WHERE c.customerNumber NOT IN ($dealerNum)
AND   c.customerNumber     IN (SELECT Customer FROM Orders where Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE -  6 MONTHS AND CURRENT_DATE           )
AND   c.customerNumber NOT IN (SELECT Customer FROM Orders where Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 18 MONTHS AND CURRENT_DATE - 6 MONTHS)
```

Comment: Very clear way to write it, although it does need two table scans on Orders

Comment: Well that would depend on what indexes you have on the Orders Date column. Check out the access plan.

Comment: The other answer will group over all the rows in the `Orders` table so would likely be slower than my version I suspect